# How to change Android background colour every second

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need set the background colour of the application every second from an ARGB value, so far most attempts have told me 'only the original thread can touch it's views', so I was wondering if there was a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin, you want to use `Activity.RunOnUIThread` to run code on the UI thread. You can only update the UI from the UI thread - there are no exceptions to this rule.

```
RunOnUiThread (() => 
    // Code to run on UI thread here
);
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/System.Action/

Further reading:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can only update a view from the main (UI) thread. There are many ways to schedule UI updates periodically - you can use [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) or [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) but really the easiest way for a simple job like you want is just use a Handler (java):

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable job = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Set background color

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    job.run();
```

Should translate directly into C#.

Comment: [@Dan2899](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5669940/dan2899), you can post your code before/after `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`

Comment: @Dan2899 you use that code whever you want to start changing the background color, for example in onCreate